# Access to CSR extensions in trusted['extensions'] on agents

Tags: puppet

I've migrated from puppet master on Apache/passenger to pupetmaster. As a result my puppet agents aren't getting any CSR extensions which were served by puppet master behind Apache.

I'm able to see those extensions on master using `puppet cert print <agent's fqdn>`:

```
X509v3 extensions:
    Netscape Comment: 
        .(Puppet Ruby/OpenSSL Internal Certificate
    Puppet Node Role Name: 
        ..ci_server
```

But on the node those extensions aren't available:

```
root@jenkins:~# puppet apply -e 'notify { "${trusted['extensions']}": }'
Notice: Compiled catalog for jenkins in environment production in 0.02 seconds
Notice: {}
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[{}]/message: defined 'message' as '{}'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.23 seconds
```

On both machines, agent and master, I'm using puppet 5.5.2. What should I do to force puppetserver to serve CSR extensions data to agents?

Comment: I'm not sufficiently confident to offer this as a formal answer, but as far as I can tell, `puppetserver` does not have a mechanism for introducing extensions into certs at its own initiative.  It does, however, transfer extensions requested in CSRs into signed certs, as described [in the manual](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/ssl_attributes_extensions.html).